# Xamarin Android Bluetooth Socket Connection fails

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin, bluetooth, connection

I am trying to create a sample Xamarin Android app to connect devices over bluetooth.

I get below error when i try to connect the bluetooth socket

```
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11643 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:15 
  at Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.Connect () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.cs:141 
  at Bluetooth.Droid.Activities.Bluetooth.BluetoothActivity.PairedDevicesListView_ItemClick (System.Object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView+ItemClickEventArgs e) [0x00094] in C:\Git\Bluetooth\Bluetooth\Bluetooth.Droid\Activities\Bluetooth\BluetoothActivity.cs:92 
  --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace ---
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:517)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:528)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:320)
    at mono.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor.n_onItemClick(Native Method)
    at mono.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor.onItemClick(AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

You can find my sample at https://github.com/sstechGitHost/Bluetooth.git

Thanks,
Nahid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are pairing with UUID which is not supported on another device. Here is the sample code to solve this. Please keep in mind this solution might require some robustness, this is just proof of concept. People says that FetchUuidsWithSdp is not very stable, so you might want to register for broadcast action to get UUIDs  or something like that. Now the code. 
Instead of

```
BluetoothSocket btSocket = btDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
```

I used

```
ParcelUuid[] uuids = null;
                if (btDevice.FetchUuidsWithSdp())
                {
                    uuids = btDevice.GetUuids();
                }
                if ((uuids != null) && (uuids.Length > 0))
                {
                    foreach (var uuid in uuids)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            btSocket = btDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.Uuid);
                            btSocket.Connect();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ex: " + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and was able to connect to another device with UUIDs

```
0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb    
00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb    
00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacafe
```

but not "
Serial" you were using.

Comment: Also, your portable class library uses namespace Bluetooth which creates some confusion on intellisence. You might want to rename it.

Comment: I tried you changes and it works. However i am not sure why FetchUUIDSWithSdp() returns so many uuids. I exit the loop the moment i get connected. I also pushed a new project in github with non-confusing namespaces. It can be downloaded https://github.com/sstechGitHost/BluetoothDemo.git                                                                                   So far i have achieved scanning, pairing and socket connection. I am now looking forward to data exchange between devices. If any pointers, feel free to update the source code.    Thank you so much.

Comment: if it works please accept the answer. If you have more problems in the future you can publish new question

Comment: @YuriS I am getting the following error when I run your code. Any issue with mine?
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret