# Error: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1 when trying to connect to a bluetooth device on xamarin forms android

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

`read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1` I get a Java.IO.IOException when I am trying to connect with a bluetooth device on xamarin forms android. I get it when I try to connect to the device that I found. this row: `myConnection.thisSocket.Connect();``

Any idea how I can fix this crash for happening? I found the device I am looking for just fine but when I try to connect to it it gives me problems.

Interface that I call on my shared code:

```
public interface IBluetooth
{
    void connect();
}
```

This is my code:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(blueToothAndroid))]
namespace myProject.Droid
{

public class blueToothAndroid : IBluetooth
{

BluetoothConnection myConnection = new BluetoothConnection();

public void connect ()
{
        myConnection = new BluetoothConnection();
        myConnection.getAdapter();
        myConnection.thisAdapter.StartDiscovery();

        try 
        {
            myConnection.getDevice();
            myConnection.thisDevice.SetPairingConfirmation(false);
            myConnection.thisDevice.SetPairingConfirmation(true);
            myConnection.thisDevice.CreateBond();
        } 

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        myConnection.thisAdapter.CancelDiscovery();

        _socket = myConnection.thisDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        myConnection.thisSocket = _socket;
        myConnection.thisSocket.Connect(); //Crash here 
}
}
```

Class:

```
public class BluetoothConnection
{
    public void getAdapter() { this.thisAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter; }
    public void getDevice() { this.thisDevice = (from bd in this.thisAdapter.BondedDevices where bd.Name == "HC-05" select bd).FirstOrDefault(); }
    public BluetoothAdapter thisAdapter { get; set; }
    public BluetoothDevice thisDevice { get; set; }
    public BluetoothSocket thisSocket { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` instead `CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord`

Comment: I still get the crash with that change

Comment: Are you have added permissions?

Comment: And you can try use `_socket=myConnection.thisDevice.GetUuids().ElementAt(0);`. This method returns the supported features (UUIDs) of the remote device. In Your case bonded device with name "HC-05"

Comment: I get this if i try that: `Cannot implicity convert type Android.OSParcelUuid to Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket`

Comment: You right, but what about it : `_socket=myConnection.thisDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myConnection.thisDevice.GetUuids().ElementAt(0).Uuid);`

Comment: Darn it! Code runs but i still get the same annoying crash!!

Comment: Here you have similar problem https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30055/connecting-to-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-xamarin-android

Comment: Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306303/xamarin-android-bluetooth-socket-connection-fails/40311305#40311305